# My compiler doesn't parse escape sequences as expected

Tags: gcc, makefile, escaping

I am trying to run static analysis on my code using a tool. The Makefile contains:

```
export TASK=MY_TASK_NAME
my_static_code_tool.exe <arguments> -- gcc <arguments..> -D__TASK_NAME__=\"$(TASK)\" -o missionFile.o missionFile.c
```

I find that this executes without an issue on RedHat but fails to run on my Cygwin environment. I assign __TASK_NAME__ variable to an unsigned char in a C file such as:

```
const unsigned char TASK_NAME[] = __TASK_NAME__;
```

I get the error as:

> gcc: no input files

I am very sure my arguments are all correct and I am referring to sources in the correct directory. To me it looks as if the `--` stops the parsing of escape sequences in the command on Windows. Can anybody help me with a workaround?

Comment: It has nothing to do with gcc not parsing - it has to do with gcc not being supplied [input] files that it expects. No files, nothing to parse/compile. So, what calls gcc (eg. what is "my_static_code_tool"?), and why is not supplying the expected parameters? Does this tool simply have an environment [in]compatibility (eg. does it use a different shell to launch gcc)?

Comment: I do not understand completely. My assumption is gcc does not need parameters to be supplied by the tool for it function. The tool needs the compiled objects. And gcc has the source file, the object file name and the parameters needed to perform compilation. I want to also say if i remove the --, the compilation runs fine without this error.

Comment: **"gcc: no input files"** - so, gcc is not getting valid source/files/configuration and bails immediately.

Comment: There is nothing special about `--` in standard shells. That is an argument understood by particular programs, to do different things. In git, ie, it's used like `git checkout rev -- file`, but the `--` has no inherent shell magic and does not change *what* the shell invokes the git command with; the `file` part is still subject to all normal shell parsing rules. (Now the quotes\escapes\variables may be handled differently in different shells.. and Windows slightly alters *how* executable parameters are supplied, although Cygwin attempts to hide that.)

Answer (score 0):

The `--` is used by the tool to introduce the compiler and its arguments [and thereby inform the tool that the following is compiler specific]. The GCC had all the required source/files/configuration defined in the Makefile. However it was not processed completely in the Cygwin shell (the command processing stopped with the escaping hence the corresponding gcc error).

The solution I employed to make this work was pre-processor stringification.

C file:

```
#define STRINGIFY_IT(str) STRING_OF(str)
#define STRING_OF(str) #str

const unsigned char TASK_NAME[] = STRINGIFY_IT(__TASK_NAME__);
```

Makefile:

```
export TASK=MY_TASK_NAME
my_static_code_tool.exe <arguments> -- gcc <arguments..> -D__TASK_NAME__=$(TASK) -o missionFile.o missionFile.c
```

So, if any of you face such problems in the future with 3rd party tools, try not to pass string arguments through the command line to GCC (as they will need to be escaped and might break the command)